# No vbox guest modules load in Debian guest after update Virtualbox from v6 to v7

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-module, guest-additions

After updated Virtualbox from v6 to v7 on Window 10 - I installed extension pack for v7 and then reinstalled guest additions for the guest.
The guest is Debian-based AntiX with kernel 4.9. I have also installed the headers for the kernel.

However - the resolution do not change when I resize the window. I saw that no `vboxdrv` exists and when I try to see the modules loaded - I get this:

```
$> lsmod | grep vbox
vboxguest             256962  2
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that VirtualBox 7 does not auto resize if the VBox window size is greater than 1920x1080. Try selecting "View" -> "Virtual Screen 1," select a smaller resolution with the same aspect ratio, and scale it up as needed.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about this. However, trying to change the resolution from there does nothing :( ...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the variant to create a new VM and `scp` everything from the "broken" one. So I created the same VM - AntiX - and installed guest additions - and all worked as expected - I was able to change screen resolution.

However, I noticed that the kernel on the new VM is 5.10, while on the "broken" one was 4.9. So - I upgraded the kernel of the broken one - and voila! - I got the guest additions to work again :)